# Creating tuples from types list

Tags: c++, templates, boost, tuples, fusion

I have an old code with the following semantic:

```
template <class Columns>
void doThings( Columns&& cols )
{
   // internal cols processing..
}
```

Calling side can be:

```
doThings( boost::fusion::vector_tie<anyVar1, anyVar2> );
doThings( boost::fusion::vector_tie<anyVar1, anyVar2> );
doThings( boost::fusion::make_tuple());  // etc..
```

I need to refactor `doThings` to accept the list of *types?* to create tuples vector inside - hide it in internal implementation. it will depend on some internal type.

For example I want to do something like this (types list are already known):

```
template <class Types>
void doThings( Types&& types)
{
   // pseudo code
   auto internalVt = boost::fusion::vector_tie(types.begin(), types.end(),
         [](Type& t) 
         {
             return makeMyType(t); 
         });
    };

// pseudo code
int anyVar1;
char anyVar2[100];

doThings( some_container<anyVar1, anyVar2> );
//or any type
doThings( some_container<int, char[100]> );
```

Is it doable? How it can be done?

Comment: What about [std::forward_as_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)

Comment: If you want to handle lists of types then you might want to look at some template metaprogramming libraries like Brigand or Metal...

Comment: Seems to me like you want to extract the template arguments from `some_container` and pack them into a `boost::fusion::tuple`, or am I misunderstanding you? Also while we're talking about template metaprogramming libraries, maybe look into Boost.MPL considering you're already using Boost

Comment: You're right I tried to extract the template arguments from some_container and pack them into a boost::fusion::tuple. Will look at Boost.MPL